# How can I correctly design relation of few different entities (one-many) that relate to one common?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I have few entities that related to each other (just a sample):

```
------User----------
->(One) Type
->(One) Company
-   Name

------Type----------
->(Many) User
-   Name

------Job------------
->(Many) User
->(Many) Type
-   Name

------Company-----
->(Many) Users
->(Many) Job
-   Name

(Name it's just a text.)
```

And I want to have many Names (aliases) for each row of entities and store it in one other table. 
I have create new entity Name and configure EF next:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => et.Names);
modelBuilder.Entity<Type>().HasMany(e => et.Names);
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasMany(e => et.Names);
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(e => et.Names);
```

It creates one table that looks loke this:

```
[Id],
[Name],
[User_Id],
[Type_Id],
[Job_Id],
[Company_Id]
```

(Can I awoid many _Ids any how?)

And when I try to set cascade deleting it throw me exception ".may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths".

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(pt => pt.Names)
                .WithOptional()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

What is the best way to do this using entity framework?

Comment: Pretty much what w.brian answered. If you sit and think about it, it is only logical (and inevitable) that your Name table ended up with multiple foreign key columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution may be to have a distinct "Name" Entity for each entity that requires many Names.  It would result in a true one-to-many mapping at the database level, but require a separate table for each.  It should also prevent the cascading issue.